# Can't uninstall default search module because the Commerce Base module is required

Tags: commerce, search, 9

I want to use Search API + Solr on my Drupal (& Drupal commerce) site.
The tutorials recommend to uninstall the core Search module.
However, I can't:
the UI at page /admin/modules has Search module checked and grayed out and trying `drush pmu search` results in the following output:

```
In ModuleInstaller.php line 432:
                                                                                                          
The following reasons prevent the modules from being uninstalled: The Commerce Base module is required
```

I am using Drupal 9.4.5, with all modules up-to-date. I installed it with the commerce_base installation profile as suggested at https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/installation.

I didn't try it on a fresh install, but even if it works there, I would prefer to be able to modify my site as needed rather than starting from scratch -- any ideas how to start debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Search API* module isn't a [drop-in replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-in_replacement) for the *Search* module. This means that modules that expect the *Search* module to be installed won't work if you replace the *Search* module with the *Search API* module.

It could also be the *Commerce Base* profile copied its dependencies from the *Standard* profile and included the Search module, even if that module isn't necessary, or the *Commerce Base* profile dependencies haven't been updated and the *Search* module is now not required. In these cases, uninstalling the *Search* module and replacing it with the *Search API* module won't cause any issue on the site.

You can verify this is the case by creating a test site where the *Composer Base* dependencies are changed to exclude the *Search* module and include the *Search API* module and checking everything works as expected, including other Commerce modules you are using on your site.
(It could be there are Commerce modules that require the *Search* module but don't add it as their dependency, thinking the *Search* module is already a dependency for the *Commerce Core* module or any other Commerce module they need.)

On the issue queue for the *Commerce Base* profile, there is [Replace core search with Search API](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce_base/issues/4), which is stalled since July 24, 2017 (the day that issue has been created).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is not possible [commerce_base requires the core search module](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce_base/blob/9.x/commerce_base.info.yml). I mean that you are not encountering a bug but rather a consequence of using that install profile.

Comment: Thanks! 
So, if I edited the commerce_base.info.yml file (say replacing search with search_api), I would be able to uninstall the module I suppose. Is it a terrible idea -- or will search_api work as a replacement?

Comment: If the *Search* module is effectively used by one of the modules installed by the *Commerce Base* profile, it won't work, since the *Search API* module doesn't implement the same classes/functions/methods implemented by the *Search* module. Even a view that uses a plugin that takes data from the *Search* module won't work.

Comment: It could also be the *Commerce Base* profile copied its dependencies from the *Standard* profile, and included the *Search* module even if that module isn't necessary. To verify this is the case, you should create a test site and check what happens when the profile dependencies are changed as you described in your comment.

Comment: As a side note, [Replace core search with Search API](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce_base/issues/4) is a *Commerce Base* issue opened in 2017. Since then, there have not been any progress.